# NoReverseMatch at /login/ (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error at login/ , when it redirects to profile.html , if i login through other pages where it redirects to another page, then it works fine , but when I click on the login button which redirects to the profile.html page , I get the NoReverseMatch error. Do you know what is wrong in this code ? , I can't seem to find the fault.

[NoReverseMatch Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq3tj.png)

profile.html

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-10 m-auto order-xl-2 mb-5 mb-xl-0">
        <div class="card card-profile shadow">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-3 order-lg-2">
              <div class="card-profile-image">
                  <img
                    src="{{ u.profile.image.url }}"
                    class="rounded-circle"
                    width="160px"
                    height="160px"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="card-header text-center border-0 pt-8 pt-md-4 pb-0 pb-md-4"
          ></div>
          <div class="card-body pt-0 pt-md-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card-profile-stats d-flex justify-content-center mt-md-5"
                >

                  <div>
                    <span class="heading">{{ u.profile.friends.count }}</span>
                    {% if request.user == u %}
                    <span class="description"
                      ><a href="{% url 'friend_list' %}">Friends</a></span
                    >
                    {% else %}
                    <span class="description">Friends</span>
                    {% endif %}
                    <span class="heading">{{ post_count }}</span>
                    <span class="description"
                      ><a href="{% url 'user-posts' u.username %}"
                        >Posts</a
                      ></span
                    >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
              <h3 class="user_link"><a href="{% url 'user-posts' u.username %}">{{ u }}</a></h3>
              <p>{{ u.profile.bio }}</p>
              <hr class="my-2" />
              {% if request.user == u %}
              <a class="btn btn-info edit_btn" href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}"
                >Edit Profile</a
              >
              {% else %} {% if button_status == 'not_friend' %}
              <small
                ><a
                  class="btn btn-secondary"
                  href="/users/friend-request/send/{{ u.username }}"
                  >Add Friend</a
                ></small
              >
              {% elif button_status == 'friend_request_sent' %}
              <small
                ><a
                  class="btn btn-warning"
                  href="/users/friend-request/cancel/{{ u.username }}"
                  >Cancel Request</a
                ></small
              >
              {% elif button_status == 'friend_request_received' %}
              <small
                ><a
                  class="btn btn-secondary mr-2"
                  href="/users/friend-request/accept/{{ u.username }}"
                  >Accept Request</a
                ></small
              >
              <small
                ><a
                  class="btn btn-danger"
                  href="/users/friend-request/delete/{{ u.username }}"
                  >Reject Request</a
                ></small
              >
              {% else %}
              <small
                ><a
                  class="btn btn-danger"
                  href="/users/friend/delete/{{ u.username }}"
                  >UnFriend</a
                ></small
              >
              {% endif %} {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def my_profile(request, slug):
        p = request.user.profile
        you = p.user
        sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=you)
        rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=you)
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_name=you)
        friends = p.friends.all()
        artwork = Music.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
        tracks = Music.objects.all()

        # is this user our friend 
        button_status = 'none'
        if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all():
            button_status = 'not_friend'

            # if we have sent him a friend request
            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=you)) == 1:
                        button_status = 'friend_request_sent'
            

            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
                        button_status = 'friend_request_received'
            
        
        data = {
            'music' : json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', Music.objects.all()))
        }
        

        context = {
                'u': you,
                'button_status': button_status,
                'friends_list': friends,
                'sent_friend_requests': sent_friend_requests,
                'rec_friend_requests': rec_friend_requests,
                'post_count': user_posts.count,
                'artwork': artwork,
                'tracks': tracks,
                'data': json.dumps(data)
            }

        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you share the login view and the full traceback

Comment: I am using  "auth_views.LoginView.as_view" , I've added the console output after the error occurs

Comment: What is the value of `LOGIN_URL` in your settings?

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'my_profile'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

Comment: There's your issue, the "my_profile" url has a required "slug" parameter and the login redirect does not pass any parameters. You need to change "my_profile" to not require any parameters or use a different url

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to have the user slug at the end of 'my_profile' url , do i need to request this from user after login ?

Comment: You can access the current user via `request.user` so you shouldn't need to pass anything in the URL to identify them

Comment: If you want each user to have a unique URL for their profile you could change the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to be a view that again redirects the user to their profile with the slug included

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip